# TFS 2008 Upgrade to new sql server database

Tags: tfs

We have Team Foundation Server 2008 installed on one server (TFSserv) and the database on another (DB1serv). We want to move the databases for TFS on to a new server (DB2serv), but leave TFS untouched.

I can't seem to find any documentation on this kind of move. Its seems like it should be pretty straight forward, but without any documentation we're not sure how much is involved.

Any help or links in the right direction are much appreciated. And I've already read [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404879(v=VS.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404879%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) These are different situations.

I guess it is kind of like the "move from single-server to dual-server," but I'm not sure if the steps provided will be viable or not, if anyone can confirm or deny.